# Two click events for the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I have a click event attached to an element's onClick attribute and also a click event that fires on any element with a specific class. The element's onClick event causes a panel on the page to close. The class's onClick event causes the page to scroll to an element lower on the page.

The problem is that both seem to fire at the same time causing the page to scroll beyond the targeted element. Here is a code sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.proceed').on("click", function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).closest('.item-section').next().offset().top
    }, 2000);
  })
});

function openPanel() {
  var rb1 = $("#radioButton1").is(':checked');
  alert("Clicked");
  $('#containerBox1').toggle(rb1);
}
```

```css
.item-section {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="item-section">
    <p>Choose a food</p>
    <input type="radio" id="radioButton1" name="food" value="pizza" onclick="openPanel()">Pizza<br>
    <div id="containerBox1" style="display: none;">
      <p>Choose a topping</p>
      <input type="radio" name="topping" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
      <input type="radio" name="topping" value="vegetarian">Vegetarian<br>
      <button class="proceed">Proceed to next section</button>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="burger" class="proceed">Burger<br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="fish" class="proceed">Fish
  </div>
  <div class="item-section">
    <p>Drink selection would be here</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this keeping in mind that my real code is much larger than the sample provided and has more classes and buttons.

Comment: If you want them both to happen but in a better order you'll probably need to look into 'deferreds' and the $.when.apply() stuff. It can get complex quite quickly. Alternatively look into 'promises', as that is a similar kind of thing. Too complex to explain here though - google is your friend! Using those will allow you to wait for one thing to happen before another.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

- extract the `.proceed` click handler to a named function
- call that named function from the `.proceed` click handler
- in `openPanel`, do whatever the function needs to do, then call the scroll handler, then call `stopPropagation` on the event

In other words, don't allow two click handlers to fire for your radio button, but have one click handler that does both tasks and then stops propagation.

Comment: I tried this, however the class level click event fires before the element click event. Since not all .proceed classes have separate click events and each of the elements that have click events have their own unique click events, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: perhaps then you can do what i suggested, but don't attach the class level handler to the elements in question.  something like `$('.proceed').not('#radioButton1')`, so that the class one never fires on that radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `onclick` events. Just process the one for `.proceed` and check to see if rb1 is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.proceed').on("click", function() {
        var rb1 = $("#radioButton1").is(':checked');
        if( rb1 ) {
            alert("Clicked");
            $('#containerBox1').toggle(rb1);
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).closest('.item-section').next().offset().top
        }, 2000);
    })
});
```